# Do I need a TB test for my Tier 4 uk visa?

Tags: student-visa

I finished an international foundation year in the UK and came back to Nigeria to apply for my 3-year Visa in the main university. According to the gov.uk site which states: You won’t need a TB test "if you lived for at least 6 months in a country where TB screening is not required by the UK, and you’ve been away from that country for no more than 6 months". I stayed in the UK from September 29th 2016 - 20th July 2017. Do I qualify to not take a TB test?

Comment: What is your uncertainty, as you've answered your own question: you were in the UK for a year, it's been under two months since you left. How long will you be in Nigeria before re-entering the UK? That would determine whether a TB test would be required.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just a bit nervous. Don't want to miss any vital information. I will apply on Monday and use the Super Priority Service.